# Can't bind with port 21 on Python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to build a simple ftp server with python, but I get an error:
"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"
As I understand, it's because of the port number, but what should I do?

Here is the code:

```
import socket

HOST = ''              
PORT = 21      
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
conn.send("220")
data = conn.recv(1024)
print data
conn.send("331 Password required for", data[5:])
conn.close()
```

Please help..

Comment: Unless you're root/admin you cannot bind to ports under 1024 on Unix and OSX systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a problem from the firewall or the antivirus. Try to disable them for a quick test. If it works, start them again, and setup some exceptions for your program.

You may also have another program currently using the port (Apache, IIS, or else). Only one program can access one port.

Comment: Thanks! I installed FileZilla server on my computer and forgot to completley close it, that was that problem.. Thank you again..